# How can I export dynamic paginated data into PDF?

Tags: angularjs, pagination, html2canvas, export-to-pdf

I'm struggling with export functionality in angularJS. I have a table consisting of dynamic data. As it contains a lot of data, I'm using dir-paginate. Pagination has worked for me fine. But when it comes to export, current page data is only exporting and not others.
Below is my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped" ng-if="worklist.finalarr.length>0">
     <thead>
         <th>S.No</th>
         <th>User</th>
         <th>Contact Name</th>
         <th>Company Name</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>City</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr dir-paginate="data in worklist.finalarr| filter:search|itemsPerPage:10" id="export">
              <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
              <td>{{data.empid}}</td>
              <td>{{data.name}}</td>
              <td>{{data.firmname}}</td>
              <td>{{data.contact}}</td>
              <td>{{data.city}}</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="10" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" style="float:right" ng-if="worklist.finalarr.length>0">
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

Below is one of my attempts for exporting data using html2canvas (controller.js):

```
$scope.export = function(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('export'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("demo"+".pdf");
        }
    });
}
```

I know that html2canvas helps in capturing the webpage data that is only present on the view. So please help me out with an alternative.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: your question is the first to pop up and was viewed many time - too bad you never added the solution